# How to exclude product images programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image

I want to mark some of the product images as excluded against some products. I tried this link http://www.magecoders.com/blog/2013/05/programmatically-exclude-product-images-in-magento/ so far. But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to exclude the images by removing them using the same code but with a small change. Before doing any of the following, BACKUP your database.

Change this

```
$mediaApi->update($_product->getId(),$item['file'],$data);
```

To this

```
$mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(),$item['file']);
```

It will remove the image from displaying in admin, but the actual image will remain under media folder.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');

class ITEMS
{
    public function index()    
    {
        $productIds = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getAllIds();
        if(is_array($productIds)) {
            foreach($productIds as $productId) {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                //get all images
                $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
                $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
                $mediaGalleryAttribute = $attributes['media_gallery'];
                //if there are images
                if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
                    //loop through the images
                    foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){
                        $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $image['file'], array('exclude' => true));
                    }
                    echo "Product ".$product->getSku()." images excluded <br>";
                    $product->save();
                }       
            }
        }
    }
}

$obj = new ITEMS();
$obj->index();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Successfully able to exclude the images by simple below code.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->_productSku);

if ($product->getId()){
     $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
     $items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());
     foreach($items as $item){
         $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
         //$mediaApi->save();
     }
}
    $product->save();
```